# how to get target device's hardware details to work with windows 10 IoT

Tags: windows, windows-10-iot-core, winpe

I have a device and i want to integrate it with Windows 10 IoT. Before that i need to analyze the hardware components of the device. In Windows 7 we have WINPE tap.exe which will generate a `dism.pmq` with all the hardware device information.

I tried searching but i could not find anything. Is there any way to find the hardware details of the device for Windows 10 IoT environment?

I need these information so that i can create my bsp.config.xml file with the required info.

Comment: Was there a particular board type you wanted this for? Eg. Raspberry Pi's. Or are you hoping to create something generic for all hardware?

Comment: I am trying to create for the board i am having.

Comment: @PradeepG, did you ever find the answer to this?